# load web page with object HTML

Tags: html, css, drupal-7, bioinformatics

I made a website bioinformatics tools , I tried calling the Galaxy tools on my website using a script < object> < / object> but does not appear blank view. Is there something wrong??

I use Drupal web CMS

this my script

```
<style>
.konten {
    min-height: 800px;
        margin: 5px  5px  5px  5px;
    border: solid 2px #DDD;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
</style>

<div class="konten">
    <object width="100%" height="900px" type="text/html" data="http://127.0.0.1:8081/root/"></object >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the problem is that Galaxy runs locally (the URL `http://127.0.0.1` refers to [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)) and that your Drupal CMS is hosted somewhere else. So the Drupal CMS can't access Galaxy. To solve your issue, I assume you will have to configure Galaxy so that is publicly accessible.

Comment: how to publicly accessible galaxy?

Comment: There are several options. You could for example [install Galaxy in the cloud](https://wiki.galaxyproject.org/CloudMan?action=show&redirect=Admin%2FCloud) or use one of the [Publicly Accessible Galaxy Servers](https://wiki.galaxyproject.org/PublicGalaxyServers).